# PowerMock failing to initialize final class

Tags: mockito, powermock, robolectric

I am using Robolectric 3.3.2 and PowerMock to unit test a final class.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(sdk = 23)
@PrepareForTest({ FinalClass.class})
public class FragmentTest {

    private TestFragment mFragment;
    private TestActivity mActivity;

    private FinalClass mFinalClassMock;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception{

        mFinalClassMock = PowerMockito.mock(FinalClass.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(FinalClass.class).withAnyArguments()
                    .thenReturn(mFinalClassMock);
        mActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(TestActivity.class)
                            .create().start().resume().get();
        mFragment = new TestFragment();

    }
}
```

is failing with below exception.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.android.contacts.common.preference.ContactsPreferences
>       at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:447)
>       at org.mockito.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
>       at org.mockito.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:217)
>       at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:378)
>       at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:318)
>       at org.powermock.api.mockito.repackaged.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass(ClassImposterizer.java:123)
>       at org.powermock.api.mockito.repackaged.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:57)
>       at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(MockCreator.java:111)
>       at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.mock(MockCreator.java:59)
>       at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock(PowerMockito.java:143)

I am using JUNIT 4.12 and Powermock 1.6.4. 
Changed versions of junit and powermock as suggested in another post, but no success.
Anyone faced this issue recently ?

Comment: I cannot give a definitive answer without seeing the whole code. However I think you either forgot the `@RunWith` or `@PrepareForTest` annotation which are both needed.

Comment: I do have @RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class) and @PrepareForTest({FinalClass.java}). Sorry i cannot post the code in current form without lot of name changes.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: You don't need to post your full test code. Reduce the problem to its minimum, and write an example around that showing your problem. We cant help with questions asking for "there bug in my code, but there no code in this question" questions.

Comment: @GhostCat ..Sorry , I just updated the question with code and complete exception

Answer (score 0):

Adding a rule inside the class seems to fix the issue

```
@Rule
public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();
```